# Why is my custom selectOneRadio layout not working with PrimeFaces 5.1?

Tags: primefaces, jboss7.x, jsf-2.2

I'm migrating my project from version 5.0 to version 5.1 of PrimeFaces.
I have a p:selectOneRadio with custom layout that works fine with version 5.0 but not with 5.1.
It seems that the itemIndex is not working.

This is my layout:

```html
<p:selectOneRadio id="incidentRadio" value="#{backingBean.option}" layout="custom">  
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="existingIncident" itemValue="existingIncident" />  
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="newIncident" itemValue="newIncident" />
</p:selectOneRadio> 
...
<p:radioButton id="optIncident1" for="incidentRadio" itemIndex="0"/>  
<h:outputLabel for="optIncident1" value="existingIncident" />
...
<p:radioButton id="optIncident2" for="incidentRadio" itemIndex="1"/>  
<h:outputLabel for="optIncident2" value="newIncident" />
```

The behaviour is the following:

- When I select the first radio button (optIncident1), it actually passes the value of the second radio button (optIncident2) to the backing bean.
- When I select the second button, it gives me a validation error:

  > formactionCall:tabViewCall:incidentRadio: Validation Error: Value is not valid

Is this a bug in 5.1?

I am using Jboss 7.1.1.Final with javax.faces-2.1.12.

Comment: Showcase seems to be working… check the releasenotes and issuelist if maybe somthing was fixed since the 5.1 release

Comment: I've check them both, but I douldn't find anything about it.

Comment: I've check them both, but I couldn't find anything about it. I am using the last update available for version 5.1 (5.1.12).